# javascript remove element from object array if key not exist

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to compare 2 arrays by values for the keys. If "target" or "source" from the "links" array are not one of the "id"s from the "nodes" array, the corresponding array must be removed from "links".

from:

```
{
    "nodes":[
        {
            "id": b,
            "year": 3
        },
        {
            "id": c,
            "year": 1
        },
                {
            "id": d,
            "year": 2
        }
    ],
    "links":[
        {
            "source": a,
            "target": b
        },
        {
            "source": a,
            "target": c
        },
        {
            "source": b,
            "target": a
        }
        {
            "source": c,
            "target": d
        }
    ]
}
```

result:

```
{
    "nodes":[
        {
            "id": b,
            "year": 3
        },
        {
            "id": c,
            "year": 1
        },
                {
            "id": d,
            "year": 2
        }
    ],
    "links":[
        {
            "source": c,
            "target": d
        }
    ]
}
```

it would be very nice if someone could help me solve this problem with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `reduce` method can do this for you:

```js
let nodes = [{
      "id": 'b',
      "year": 3
   },
   {
      "id": 'c',
      "year": 1
   },
         {
      "id": 'd',
      "year": 2
   }
];
let links = [
   {
      "source": 'a',
      "target": 'b'
   },
   {
      "source": 'a',
      "target": 'c'
   },
   {
      "source": 'b',
      "target": 'a'
   },
   {
      "source": 'c',
      "target": 'd'
   }
];


const filteredLinks = links.reduce((p,c,i) => {
   if(
      nodes.some(x => x.id===c.source) 
      && 
      nodes.some(x => x.id===c.target)
   )
   {
      p.push(c) 
   }; 
   return p  
},[]);

console.log(filteredLinks)
```

Answer (score 2):

first create a set with the ids of nodes

```
const ids = nodes.map(node => node.id);
const idSet = new Set(ids);
```

then filter the links array like this:

```
const filteredLinks = links.filter(link => idSet.has(link.target) && idSet.has(link.source))
```

then the response will be

```
return { nodes, links: filteredLinks }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
links.filter((link)=>{
    let sourceMatch = nodes.find((node)=>{
        return node.id == link.source;
    });

    let targetMatch = nodes.find((node)=>{
        return node.id == link.target;
    });

    return sourceMatch && targetMatch;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using double `forEach` and `splice`.

```js
const obj = JSON.parse('{"nodes":[{"id": "b","year": 3},{"id": "c","year": 1},{"id": "d","year": 2}],"links":[{"source": "a","target": "b"},{"source": "a","target": "c"},{"source": "b","target": "a"},{"source": "c","target": "d"}]}');

obj.nodes.forEach((v,k) => {
obj.links.forEach((q,p) => {
if(v.id !== q.target || v.id !== q.source) {
  obj.links.splice(0,p);
}
});
});
console.log(obj);
;
```